# How can I send csrf_token?

Tags: javascript, django

Good afternoon!
Please help me send csrf_token to the POST function for an authorized user. The error is, when I do user registration, error comes out: Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /data/task.
The link to the library is below (there is also a demo project for this link).
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__howtostart_python.html

Comment: The user will generally store the active CSRF as a cookie and on POST request submit it as a header required by your framework. This could be "_csrf".

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Django, you need to add the csrf_token to your registration form

```py
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   // form here
</form>
```